# Ruby on Rails - undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estive tentando inserir o alert em um form mas estou com o seguinte erro:

`undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass`

No meu form faço uma referência ao erro:

```
<%= form_for :exercice do |f|%>
 <%= render 'erro' %>
 <%= f.label :timer, "Tempo" %>
 <%= f.number_field  :timer %>
 <%= f.label :category_id, "Categoria"%>
 <%= collection_select(:exercice, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name,      prompt: "Selecione") %>
 <%= f.label :date, "Data"%>
 <%= f.date_select :date %>
 <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-large btn-success"%>
<% end %>
```

Na partição do erro tenho:

```
<% if @exercice.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errorExplanation">
   <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
   this post from being saved:</h2>
   <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Nesse caso, o sistema está criticando a linha

`<% @post.errors.any? %>`

Já no meu controller tenho:

```
class ExercicesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_exercice, only: [:destroy]

 def index
  @exercices = Exercice.all
 end

 def new
  @exercice = Exercice.new
 end

 def create
  @exercice = Exercice.new(exercice_params)
  if @exercice.save
   redirect_to exercices_path
  else
    redirect_to exercices_path
  end
 end


 def destroy
  @exercice.destroy
  redirect_to exercices_url
 end

 private

  def set_exercice
    @exercice = Exercice.find(params[:id])
  end


  def exercice_params
    params.require(:exercice).permit( :timer, :date, :category_id)
  end

end
```

Criei as rotas como patrão:

```
 Agenda::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :exercices

 end
```

E todoo código está sendo renderizado na index:

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
  <h1>Log de Exercícios</h1>
  <div class="form-inline">
   <%= render  "form" %>
  </div>
 <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Tempo</th>
    <th>Categoria</th>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

<tbody>
  <% @exercices.each do |exercice| %>

      <tr>
        <td><%= exercice.timer %></td>
        <td><%= exercice.category.name %></td>
        <td><%= l exercice.date %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Excluir', exercice, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'%></td>
      </tr>
   <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

Em vez disso:

```
def create
  @exercice = Exercice.new(exercice_params)
  if @exercice.save
    redirect_to exercices_path
  else
    redirect_to exercices_path
  end
end
```

Faça isso:

```
def create
  @exercice = Exercice.new(exercice_params)
  if @exercice.save
    redirect_to exercices_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

No caso de dar erro você não deve redirecionar, mas sim apenas renderizar a view *new*.

---

## Atualização

Bom oque está acontecendo é que você está renderizando o form na view *index*, oque inclui o seguinte código:

```
<% if @exercice.errors.any? %>
  (...)
<% end %>
```

O erro `undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass` acontece porque não existe uma instância válida para a variável `@exercice`:

```
def index
  @exercices = Exercice.all
end
```

Note como tu não tem um `@exercice`, apenas uma lista de `@exercices`.

### Oque eu te recomendo fazer:

- Crie a view `new.html.erb` na pasta `app/views/exercices` com o form de maneira idêntica como tu fez no na view *index*, incluindo a verificação de erros.
- Depois remova a verificação de erros no form que está na view *index*.

Com "verificação de erros" eu quero dizer este trecho:

```
<% if @exercice.errors.any? %>
  (...)
<% end %>
```

- E finalmente altere o código do `ExerciceController` para renderizar a view *new* em caso de erro ao salvar o objeto:

Assim:

```
def create
  @exercice = Exercice.new(exercice_params)
  if @exercice.save
    redirect_to exercices_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Isso fará com que o usuário permaneça na view *new* enquanto houver erros de validação. Porém se ele utilizar o form na view *index*, e não houver erro, ele será redirecionado para a própria view *index* novamente.

Comment: Olá @user3153542 Só que no meu caso não tenho a view New, tudo funciona em uma única página, a index! Ou seja, a path "form" é renderizada na view index. Criei esse action New nem me lembro do pq mesmo, pq no fundo não precisava, eu acho!

Comment: Bom dia @user5476 Parece que você não está seguindo as convenções do Rails, que existem justamente para permitir que outros _rails developers_ entendam mais facilmente o seu código. Por favor, edite a sua pergunta incluindo o seu `routes.rb` para eu dar uma olhada e vou tentar editar minha pergunta com a solução.

Comment: Bom dia @user3153542! Já alterei minha pergunta :)

Comment: @user5476, também já editei minha resposta.

Comment: desculpa ai pela demora, acabei esquecendo. Entendi o que você falou e acho que funciona, sendo que isso seria mais código para manter atualizado no futuro e outra, duplicação nem sempre é bom. Mas vou tentar implementar aqui.