# Porque param[“value”] esta retornando nada

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, post

Estou criando um projeto em Ruby on Rails, onde crio um grito com a seguinte rota no postman:

```
POST:http://localhost:3000/api/yells
{
    "user_id":"1",
    "title":"caneca",
    "desciption":"beber",
    "yell_type":"oferta",
    "price":"20,00",
    "categories":[{"name":"porcelana"}]
}
```

Controller #create :

```
def create
  #@yell = Yell.new(yell_params.except(:categories))
  @yell = Yell.new({title: params[:title], desciption: params[:desciption], price: params[:price], user_id: params[:user_id], yell_type: params[:yell_type]})

  Array(params[:categories]).each do |rel|
    @category = Category.find_by_name(rel[:name])
    if @category
      #only creates the relationship
    else
      @yell.categories.build(name: rel[:name]) #creates the relationship and category
    end
  end

  if @yell.save
    render json: @yell, status: :created, location: api_yell_path(@yell)
  else
    render json: @yell.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Eu estou fazendo um projeto com um amigo meu que esta fazendo o frontend, e quando ele testa na maquina dele pelo postman, substituindo o `localhost` pelo meu `ip`, cria um `yell` e as categorias, mas com todos os valores vazios.

Imagino que seja porque o `params[:values]` esta vindo nulo, mas não era para vir. Até porque na minha maquina funciona e cria tudo certinho. Ele ainda consegue nas rotas `GET` puxar tudo certinho. Tem algo que tenho que configurar no servidor ou alguma outra coisa nas rotas, ou no postman?

Alguém pode me ajudar estou realmente sem nenhuma noção de como resolver esse problema.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705545/ruby-on-rails-params-is-nil-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass

Comment: Entretanto você está fazendo referência ao "payment_type" mas no POST request não está passando como parâmetro, pelo menos no POST que você inseriu na pergunta.

Comment: Ou talvez esse -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12840/ruby-on-rails-undefined-method-errors-for-nilnilclass?rq=1

Comment: O mais estranho é que no meu postman funciona e no dele não, achei que seria algo das rota. E já tinha visto essa question, mas nelas ele fazem o tratamento para quando algo é nulo, mas meu erro é porque esta vindo nulo, era para ele esta recebendo.

Comment: Na verdade era um erro na chamada, estava esquecendo de passar o content-type no header da chamas, descobri que tinha como colocar isso no routes também colocando o seguinte parametros: `defaults: { format: 'json' }` isso vai sinalizar que todas as minhas chamadas naquele contexto são do tipo json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problemas é que meu amigo estava esquecendo de passar o Header na chamada dele, ele deveria passa um `content-type=aplication/json`.

Descobri que tem como eu definir por padrão que todas as minhas chamadas são do tipo `json`, para isso encapsulei todas as minhas chamadas à `API` com:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' }  do
  ...
end
```

não pode esquece de nos controladores que forem chamados por essa rota coloar antes do nome da classe um `Api::`

```
#nomes_controller.rb
class Api::NomesController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

Comment: É o segundo comentário que eu vejo que você mesmo responde. Nada contra. Só acho uma boa estratégia pra ganhar pontos no stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta acessar os parametros usando:

```
params[:yells][:categories}.each |rel|
end
```

Comment: Então @Ghilherme, minha maior duvida é porque funciona a chamada dessa forma como estou fazendo na minha maquina, e na dele não.

Comment: Tu colocou pouco código ali, talvez seja algo com as rotas do seu amigo. O create parece funcional.